# Xampp asking for a password only when accessed through hostname

Tags: wordpress, apache, passwords, xampp, noip

I have Xampp setup on my windows machine, with a WordPress site, when accessing it, through localhost, it runs normally, however after I linked my computer, through no-IP, for a dynamic DNS, and attempt access through the internet using the hostname, I get prompted for a username and password for some reason.

I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I didn't forward a port so it was actually redirecting to my router page and asking for username and password.

Anyhow, I found this YouTube video on how to forward a port for linksys router: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIK-RpVNAM8

Didn't realize it was more of a Network question.